# Why doesn't anything happen when I try to use this bot?

Tags: discord, bots

I am typing the message in the correct Discord channel and in the correct server. I don't think it is even detecting messages in the chat, it only shows the chat name in the name terminal. I am following this YT tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fU-kWx-OYvE&ab_channel=Indently.

```
import discord
import random

TOKEN = "MTAyOTc5OTI2MTUzMTAyNTQ4OQ.Gm2ElQ.-JLT11wrzHgXqzPIuCI8jZC3aCyN82KFyxWAQo"

client = client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("We have logged in as {0.user}" .format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    username = str(message.author).split("#")[0]
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel.name)
    print(f"{username}: {user_message} ({channel})")

    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    if message.channel.name == "general":
        if user_message.lower() == "do it jeff":
            await message.channel.send(f"My name is Jeff")
            return
        elif user_message.lower() == "stop":
            await message.channel.send(f"NEVER {username}!")
            return

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: `client = client =` looks like a typo.

Comment: Just fixed that and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bot can't read the content of the messages sent in a guild because it is missing the `message_content` intent.

You gave your bot only the default intents, which doesn't include the `message_content` one.

```
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
```

Here is how you fix it:

```
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.message_content = True
    client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

In case your bot isn't still able to read the content of the guild messages, you need also to turn on the message content intent in the Discord Developer Portal:

Select your app
Go to the "Bot" tab
Turn the `message content intent` on
Now your bot should be able to read the content of the messages sent in guilds.